# Read locale settings of windows programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, culture

I need to know the default page size (such as A4 or Letter) of the current locale/culture of the underlying O/S from a C# Winforms application.

I have seen a page from MSDN explaining this, but I've since lost the link. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I don't think default paper size is part of system locale. MS Office, however, has such a setting.

Comment: i somewhere saw a constant named something like ILocale.PageSize. i was hunting for it,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be looking for this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373799(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

i think what u need is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.pagesettings.papersize.aspx). not locale settings .

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.pagesettings.papersize.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
new PrinterSettings().DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize;
```

Answer (score 0):

See this:

using System.Drawing.Printing;

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
        PageSettings ps = doc.DefaultPageSettings;

        if (ps.Landscape)
            label1.Text = "LANDSCAPE";
        PaperSize paperSize = ps.PaperSize;

    }
```

There are many other properties of ps available which you can use.

Answer (score 0):

For the lazy, here's the code that @logeeks' answer would use:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern int GetLocaleInfo(
   uint Locale,
   uint LCType,
   [Out] StringBuilder lpLCData,
   int cchData);

public enum LCType : uint
{
    LOCALE_IPAPERSIZE = 0x0000100A,   // 1 = letter, 5 = legal, 8 = a3, 9 = a4
}

void Main()
{
    //CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
    CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"); ;

    var output = new StringBuilder();

    int result = GetLocaleInfo((uint)(culture.LCID), (uint)LCType.LOCALE_IPAPERSIZE, output, 99);

    if (result > 0)
    {
        // 1 = letter, 5 = legal, 8 = a3, 9 = a4
        Console.WriteLine(output.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("fail");
    }
}
```

References:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6341920/270348
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb688130.aspx
- http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetLocaleInfo.html
- http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetLocaleInfoEx.html